# JScrollPane not displaying on JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

The `JScrollPane` that I'm trying to implement isn't working. I want to add it to my `JTextArea`, but for some reason it doesn't want to display

```
//JTEXTBOX
textArea = new JTextArea();
textArea.setEditable(false);

//JSCROLLPANE
JScrollPane scroll1 = new JScrollPane(textArea);
scroll1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 250));
scroll1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
scroll1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

Comment: Corrected code formatting. Also if you write something like: *isn't working* then it's good if you explain what you mean with this. e.g. What output you get now and what you would expect to get.

Comment: Basic questions just in case: are you using a layout? Are you adding the textArea to any Dialog/Frame? You should try to write a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works just fine for me. I am guessing that you are adding the textarea to the component hierarchy instead of the scrollpane. Make sure that you call `parent.add(scrollpane)` and not `parent.add(textarea)`.

See this example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;

public class TestTextArea {
    private JTextArea textArea;

    public TestTextArea() {
    }

    private void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // JTEXTBOX
        textArea = new JTextArea(10, 25);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        textArea.setText("Here is my textarea\nI can finally see it.\nYeah!!! :-)");

        // JSCROLLPANE
        JScrollPane scroll1 = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scroll1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 250));
        scroll1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scroll1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        frame.add(scroll1);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TestTextArea test = new TestTextArea();
                    test.initUI();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Note: forget using `setPreferredSize` and try to hint the `JTextArea` of your preferred size by providing rows and columns in its constructor.